# GitLab Add username to origin URL

Tags: gitlab

It's very frustrating that in GitLab it doesn't have the username in the HTTP URL when you create a new project. So you have to copy the URL then when pasted into the console you then have to move back in the line and insert your username. This is very inefficient as you're already logged in.

Is there anyway to add my logged in username to the HTTP line in GitLab in the code?

[image]
[image]

A simple `username@` does the job but adding this manually each time is a pain and should be able to be done in code but after spending an hour on Google I can't find anything.

Comment: A workaround: in your ~/.ssh/config: `Host your.git.host\nUser git`

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in GitLab right now. Please submit this as feature request to http://feedback.gitlab.com.